# Compare 2 Files based on Column name Using Shell/python Script

Tags: python, shell

I came across query today on data comparison question today and I was wondering if 2 excel can be compared based on column name using shell/python script. File 2 is primary and need to have all columns . Null Columns from File 1 can be ignore.

[image]

I know we can compare 2 text files using below method but not sure about the excel.

```
file1=/var/tmp/foo.txt
file2=/var/tmp/bar.txt
sort ${file1} | grep -v '^$' > ${file1}.tmp
sort ${file2} | grep -v '^$' > ${file2}.tmp
sdiff ${file1} ${file2}
```

Any suggestions on this ?

Comment: By excel you mean .xls or .xlsx files? You can't compare them just like that, those are actually .zip archives containing all the data, styling, images, etc. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML Try to find a proper parser. I guess this one will be your help: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/

Comment: I mean .xlsx .. regular MS excel file . It will have only 1 row and heading ,

Comment: then you should go for the openpyxl

Comment: Can you guide me to sample code of column level comparison in python using openpyxl. I havent worked much on python so that would be great

Comment: No, this is a QA site, not a free tutoring site. Start with the documentation, google it and if you have many unsuccessful attempts, and google doesn't help, post a question here or open an issue on the repo's github page.  Thsi should get you going: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html#read-an-existing-workbook

Comment: Just a thought .. cant we assign heading based value to variable and then compare the variable.